# Javascript - script is working but having 2 errors in IE

Tags: javascript, jquery, internet-explorer-6

I have a video rater, same thing as the one on youporn.com (sorry but that was my reference! To see it just click on any video, scroll down a bit and you'll see it).

My script is working fine everywhere, but I am having some errors on IE and I want to get rid of them.

Here's the code that are causing the 2 issues:

```
var rater_offset = $("div#rater-bkg").offset().left;

$("div#rater-bkg").bind("mousemove.rater", function(e) {
    var rate = Math.ceil(( e.pageX - rater_offset) / 25 );
    $("div#rater-bkg > div#rater-input").width( rate * 25 );
    $("div#rater-status > p").hide().filter(".rater-"+rate).show();
});
```

So, here are the errors:

> "*Unterminated string constant*"

and

> "*Object doesn't support this property or method*"

Any hints on how I can get of these?

Thanks

Comment: What line does the error occur on?

Comment: Are you executing this script inside the jQuery document.ready?

Comment: Why are you using IE6 (even Microsoft wants people to stop using it)?

Comment: ooh im sorry! I did accept answers, sorry I didnt know !

Comment: I don't see anything in the code you posted that would cause those two errors.